# Heroku repo has disappeared when pushing my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been using heroku already for my rails app.  I have come back to do some more work on the app but when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

I get

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

but

```
git remote -v
```

gives

```
origin  git@github.com:x/guidelines.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:x/guidelines.git (push)
```

So I assume that means that the repo is there somewhere?  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't worry all is fine.

You need to go to heroku.com and get the git URL of your application from the Apps > App Name > Settings page. You're looking for `git@heroku.com:<application-name>.git`.

Back at your command line readd the heroku remote via;

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<application-name>.git
```

and you'll be then able to push to the `heroku` remote.